# How to route between modules in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am using angular2 Final for development.

I have created 3 modules.

1. AppModule
2. ProjectModule
3. DesignerModule

Previously I had only AppModule,In Which I had imported following RoutingModule & it worked fine.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ProjectManagerComponent} from './project-manager/project-manager.component';
import {DesignerComponent} from './designer/designer.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '',redirectTo: 'project-manager',pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'project-manager', component: ProjectManagerComponent },
  { path: 'designer/:id', component:DesignerComponent }  
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents=[ProjectManagerComponent,DesignerComponent]
```

But recently I have created separate NgModules for ProjectManager & Designer.

I have kept ProjectManagerComponent,DesignerComponent inside declarations in their respective modules.

I want to know if it is possible to route to these modules using same routing configuration or do I need to change something.

My Routing is not working anymore.

any inputs?

Comment: whats the final solution?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

`export const routingComponents=[ProjectManagerComponent,DesignerComponent]`

you can just

`export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);`

Since you `app.module.ts` already knows about `ProjectManagerComponent` and `DesignerComponent` from their respective modules. All that is left is to teach it where to go and find them.

Inside of your `app.module.ts` you would have

`// All the other imports
    import {routing} from './app.routes;'
    @NgModule({
      imports:[routing, /*Other Modules*/],
    })`